# Modular Vaadin Flow application. Frontend resources dynamic loading

Tags: npm, plugins, vaadin, vaadin-flow

We have a big monolithic Flow/Spring/Gradle application, and we want to introduce some modularity, with a hot-load plugin system.

Plugin are vaadin/flow independent projects with :

- web resources in META-IN/resources/frontend : javascript, CSS, images..
- eventually import of third party NPM resources

On the server side, I had some success with my prototype using pf4j and pf4j-spring

On the client side, I don't know how to tackle the problem. In a monolithic way, all frontend resources are webpacked. How can I dynamically make web resources accessible to the client ?

I have read about the notion of NPM chunking

- https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5623
- https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5339

It should also be related to the Page.loadDynamic feature

I'm missing some keys. Anyone to point me in a good direction ??

Comment: You might want to look into OSGi. The question is do you _really_ need a hot-load plugin system for your application or does a better build process (multi-project gradle build) suffice?

Comment: We have already a gradle multi-module build. Actually, the customer specifics for one customer is one gradle module. We have to build and deploy the whole platform if we change this customer-specific module. OSGI is an option for a PF4J replacement, but I think it doesn't cover the NPM resources modularisation too

Comment: Actually my prototype covers :  - dynamic deploy/undeploy of Vaadin route  - access to plugin jar static resources  It doesn't cover:  - JsModule & CSSImport injection

Comment: That's quite a lot already. Disclaimer: I am not familiar with pf4j but assuming you have some kind of event/callback that let's you know about new modules I think you can do the classpath scanning for JsModule+CssImport yourself and then use Page.addJavaScript(...), Page.addJsModule(...) and Page.addDynamicImport(...) respectively. See and https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/loading-resources/#loading-javascript-with-the-page-object and https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.7.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/page/Page.html#addDynamicImport-java.lang.String-